# How to avoid double "save password to iCloud" dialog?

Tags: ios, secsharedcredentials

In a login dialog, the username and password text fields have their `contentType` set:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   userNameTextField.textContentType = .username
   passwordTextField.textContentType = .password
}
```

Historically, the app was "manually" storing the credentials as shared credentials with `SecAddSharedWebCredential`.

However, in iOS 12.0.1 I noticed that the "save password" dialog is suddenly displayed two times on top of each other:

[image]

Is that because from iOS 11.0 on the dialog below appears automatically because `textContentType` is set and the dialog on top appears because of calling `SecAddSharedWebCredential`?

Is it documented anywhere from which iOS version onwards the dialog appears that is partly hidden in the screenshot?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @PeterRobert I will post an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to not manually store the credentials as shared credentials with SecAddSharedWebCredential anymore in iOS 11+.

So we are not calling this anymore:

```
SecAddSharedWebCredential(domain, username, password, handler)
```

Comment: what is the alternative we can use?